# Delphi: Save the output of a select statement in a Stringlist

Tags: sql, delphi

I have following Select Statement: `SHOW TABLES`.

The output is:

```
table1
table2
table3
...
```

I want to save the resultset to a `TStringList`. How can I do that?

I have searched on the Internet but found only solutions where the field name is known.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  s:string;
  list : tstringlist;
begin
  FDQuery1.open('show tables');

  with FDQuery1 do
  begin
    while not EOF do
    begin
      //list.Add();
      Next;
    end;
  end;

  ListBox1.Items.AddStrings(list);
end;
```

Comment: You have to create an instance of the stringlist, or just call `ListBox1.Items.Add()` directly without the intermediate stringlist.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't know the field name, try

```
List.Add(FDQuery1.Fields[0].AsString);
```

or

```
s := FDQuery1.Fields[0].AsString;
List.Add(s);
```

That will  add the string value of the first column in the current row of the result set returned by FDQuery1.

Btw you can get the field name (aka columnname of the query) of the field by

```
s := FDQuery1.Fields[0].FieldName;
```

Comment: Did this help you with your problem?